# How to determine whether a file is encrypted with EFS?

Tags: c#, .net, ntfs, encrypting-file-system

Is there a library method somewhere for figuring out whether a file has been encrypted with EFS? I see the `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` methods on FileInfo, but am looking for a way to query a file's state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GetFileAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28VS.85%29.aspx), and check for [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332330%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I was looking for a .net answer, but it turns out that it is similar to your suggestion: use FileInfo.Attributes and check for FileAttributes.Encrypted

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed your C# tag. Good to hear you found an answer though :)

Answer (score 6):

To expand on bdolan & matt's comment:

```
<snip>
using System.IO;
<snip>
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(uri); //uri is the full path and file name
if (fi.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Encrypted))
{
//FILE IS ENCRYPTED
}
else
{
//FILE IS SAFE
}
```